# Load an appropriately sized fullpage background image

Tags: jquery, css

I need to create a fullpage background. Therefore this would work:

```
html { 
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

So I would load a big background-image (around 2000px width), but I think this solution is quite bad as i.e. mobile diveces would also load this big image.

I tried to load the image appending to the screen size:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
    var win = $(window);

    win.resize(function() {

        var win_w = win.width(),
            win_h = win.height(),
            $bg    = $("#bg");

        // Load narrowest background image based on 
        // viewport width, but never load anything narrower 
        // that what's already loaded if anything.
        var available = [
            1024, 1280, 1366,
            1400, 1680, 1920,
            2560, 3840, 4860
        ];

        var current = $bg.attr('src').match(/([0-9]+)/) ? RegExp.$1 : null;

        if (!current || ((current < win_w) && (current < available[available.length - 1]))) {
            var chosen = available[available.length - 1];
            for (var i=0; i<available.length; i++) {
                if (available[i] >= win_w) {
                    chosen = available[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Set the new image
            $bg.attr('src', '/images/bg/' + chosen + '.jpg');
        }

        // Determine whether width or height should be 100%
        if ((win_w / win_h) < ($bg.width() / $bg.height())) {
            $bg.css({height: '100%', width: 'auto'});
        } else {
            $bg.css({width: '100%', height: 'auto'});
        }
    }).resize();
});
```

So I need a image-element like this:

```
<img id="bg" src="" style="position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0" />
```

But this isn't really a background (like the first solution). Is it possible to adapt the jquery-script to the html-background-url?
Or does anyone know a more simple solution?

I also want to load the image first (!) and after that fade the website in... I guess I need the .load()-function of jQuery for that; but I don't know how to put this in the script...

Comment: Did you try CSS media queries? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Ah.. damn. Sure. That's quite the easiest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more up-to-date media query with filters

```
@media screen and (max-width:1024px){

    img { 
          filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.largeImage.png', sizingMethod='scale');
          -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='largeImage.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
          background: url(images/largerImage.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1140px){

    img { 
          filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.largerImage.png', sizingMethod='scale');
          -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='largerImage.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
          background: url(images/largerImage.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

You can find a reference to it here 
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 2):

Use responsive design. i.e. css-only solution:

```
body {
    background-image: url("lg_image.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center; 
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
      background-image: url("xs_image.png");
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
  body {
      background-image: url("sm_image.png");
  }
}

@media (min-width: 993px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  body {
      background-image: url("lg_image.png");
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1201px) {
  body {
      background-image: url("xl_image.png");
  }
}
```

Browsers that don't support CSS3 will show lg_image.png so there is a graceful downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this with Javascript, but instead of loading based on screen size it is loading a random image int he background everytime the page is refreshed.

You do not need an  tag, or to change it's attr. You can use jQuery to change the CSS style on the body tag to load a different setting, or if you want to get away from inlining style tags (and you should) as I did, you can simply create a class for each background and apply the class to the body to change the background via jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var sWidth = screen.availWidth;
    var sHeight = screen.availHeight;

    if(sWidth > 1024){

        $("img").attr("src", "largeImage.png");

    } else if(sWidth > 1140){

        $("img").attr("src", "largerImage.png");

    }
    //and so on

})
```

Alternatively you can use css3 media Queries,

```
<style>
    @media screen and (max-width:1024px){

        img { background-image:url(largImage.png); }

    }

    @media screen and (max-width:1140px){

        img { background-image:url(largerImage.png); }

    }
</style>
```

if you need to support IE8 use respond.js it will fix issue with IE8 not supporting the css3 media query make sure you place the script tag for it after the css is loaded.

Comment: Keep in mind that IE8 doesn't support `background-size: cover` either, so the media query wouldn't help there. ;)

Comment: I didn't think of that.  I tend not worry as much about it because IE8 usage is about 10% world-wide according to global stats thats due to decrease as XP is no longer supported and vulnerable to attacks. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/end-support-help. But you could also use IE8 filters to accomplish the scaling.

Comment: Using javascript in this scenario complicates things in my opinion. CSS3 media queries will fire on resize. Also the javascript resize fires on release and will not updated as the window is being resized. CSS3 media queries fire when breakpoints are hit. If you wanted to update as its being resized you would have to use something like setInterval in your script to monitor the current screen width and update the image based on that.